# How to change default baud rate of serial monitor in VSCode with PlatformIO?

Tags: visual-studio-code, baud-rate, platformio

I have VSCode and PlatformIO plugin.
When I start serial monitor it always starts with 9600 baud rate. I'd like to change that, so it always starts with 115200.

I can change the baud rate of already running serial monitor by pressing CTRL+T, b, 115200, enter but I don't want to do this every time I start my serial monitor.

I can't find that setting anywhere. I tried adding a line `speed = 115200` to platformio.ini but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Might be using windows default serial port settings? this can be changed under device manager and properties of the serial port..

Comment: I just tried changing that under device manager, unfortunately, without success. Serial monitor started with 9600 baud rate despite the change :(

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need to add the option `monitor_baud = 115200` for your target in platformio.ini

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: Thank you very mouch! Only as a clarification, and as the same Platformio warns: `Warning! monitor_baud option is deprecated and will be removed in the next release! Please use monitor_speed instead.`

Comment: Hm. Wont work in my case: always outputs: `platformio device monitor --baud 9600`. I tried: `monitor_baud = 115200` , `monitor_speed = 115200`
as well as `speed = 115200`

Comment: for 50 years or more baud has been used but now we need to deprecate it. change for the sake of it! or do todays coders not care about history at all?

Answer (score 20):

I just added:

```
monitor_speed = 115200
```

to `platformio.ini` file and it works

> https://docs.platformio.org/en/stable/projectconf/section_env_monitor.html#monitor-speed

Comment: This is the correct answer (2020). `monitor_baud ` is now deprecated,
It's `monitor_speed `.

Comment: It started working for me, but after VSCode restart.

Answer (score 5):

I also had some issues with Serial Monitor on PlatformIO.

In order to get mine working, I had to specify:
monitor_rts = 0

The full config (platformio.ini):

```
[env:esp32dev]
platform = espressif32
board = esp32dev
framework = arduino
monitor_speed = 115200
monitor_rts = 0
```

[The full reference for monitor options is here.](https://docs.platformio.org/en/stable/projectconf/section_env_monitor.html)

Answer (score 1):

I have opened two projects in the platformio. If you continue to get a default baud rate of 9600 in platformio, even though you set `monitor_speed=115200` in `platform.ini` file, check the button "Switch PlatformIO Project Environment" next to the button "Serial Monitor" in Visual Studio Code to ensure you're on the right project. This will save you a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 0):

monitor_speed = 115200 must be under [env]

Answer (score 0):

you can open the monitor using following command

```
    pio device monitor --baud 115200
```